# run assignment rule from javascript button

Tags: java, ajax

I have a requirement to run **case assignment rule** from `javascript`. I used the below code but the assignment rule does not run.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/apex.js")} 

var updateRecord = []; 
var updateCaseRecord=[]; 
var caseToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 

if('{!Case.Status}' != 'In Progress' ) {    
    alert('The Case cannot be reversed. A case can be reversed only when it is in "In Progress" Status');  
}  
else {      
    caseToUpdate.id ='{!Case.Id}';
    caseToUpdate.status = '{!Case.Previous_Case_Status__c}';
    assignObj = new sforce.SObject("AssignmentRuleHeader");     
    assignObj.useDefaultRule = 'true';
    sforce.connection.AssignmentRuleHeader = {}
    sforce.connection.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule='true';
    //caseToUpdate.setOptions(assignObj);
    updateRecord.push(caseToUpdate);
    var result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecord); 
if (result[0].success=='false') {       
    alert(result[0].errors.message);    
} 
else {      
    location.reload();  
}    //End.  
} 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: What is the error/issue that you are getting when you execute this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `AssignmentRuleHeader` is case sensitive, Try changing it to `assignmentRuleHeader`.

Your code would then be:

```
sforce.connection.AssignmentRuleHeader = {}
sforce.connection.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = "true";
```

can also be written as:

```
sforce.connection.assignmentRuleHeader = { "useDefaultRule": "true" }
```

If this doesn't work, `true` instead of `"true"`

```
sforce.connection.assignmentRuleHeader = { "useDefaultRule": true }
```

Also you would not want `window.location.reload();` at the end outside else, otherwise it would reload after the Status check alert.

Comment: Changing the AssignmentRuleHeader to assignmentRuleHeader and useDefaultRule= true without quotes did the trick. Thanks for the help!